# Windows 8 firewall blocks browser downloads

Tags: windows-8, firewall, blocking, file-download

When using Chrome and Internet Explorer for Hotmail I can't download Word or PDF attachments. I also tried to download Adobe Reader with the same results, it was blocked. If I switch the firewall off, then downloading works as expected.

I have searched the web, but I haven't found anything useful.

Does anyone know how can I configure the firewall to stop this blocking? I've added both Chrome and Internet Explorer to the firewall's permitted list on both home and public networks, but to no avail.

I imagine any workaround for Windows 7 would be applicable too, the firewalls seem to be similar.

Comment: What is the exact message displayed when you attempt to download these files?

Comment: No message at all, it just fails silently.

Comment: Its not possible for it to fail silently.  Firefox if it even began downloading the file would display an error.  IE10 has smart filtering but even if it detects something malicious provides a way for you to download the file.

Comment: when I click on the download link in hotmail nothing happens. No message, no error, no download , it's as if the link wasn't clicked. Not sure what should come up but is it possible that the user was presented with a message that had the option of not showing displaying the message again? No point in me asking what he did because he's oblivious.

Comment: I really hate to say this , because the user assured me he reboots 3 times a day, but after I configured the firewall to allow chrome and ie and it didnt work,  he rebooted and all seems fine for now. If anything this serves to remind me and us techs of the basics when it comes to windows ... REBOOT ..REBOOT .... REBOOT ... adlib to fade.

Comment: What it proves is that clients are idiots and you should verify everything yourself.

Comment: True, and that unfortunately makes me an idiot too this time.

Comment: It makes you more foolish then idiotic